# Context Configuration Not loading beans and throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way we can load spring.xml file in a java class and load all the beans. 
For example:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*: spring.xml"})
public class springtest {

@Autowired
private PayloadRequest payloadRequest ;
}

@Component
public class PayloadRequest (){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@ImportResource("Path to file") this is used for importing xml configuration 
@Import({java classes}) this is used for importing java configuration
```

Here is link for official documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html

Answer (score 1):

To load XML configure beans into the application context use `@ImportResource`

> The recommended way is to create a separate configuration class to load this xml bean definition file.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class XmlConfiguration {
  }
```

**load multiple configs**

```
@Configuration
@Import({ AppConfigOthers.class }) //loads another JavaConfig
@ImportResource("classpath:/config/spring-web-servlet.xml")
 public class AppConfigCore {
    //...
 }
```

**By java code** Just load in `main` method

```
ApplicationContext APPLICATION_CONTEXT = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/context/application-context.xml");
```

Comment: I have created a bean for PayloadRequest class in spring.xml. When I try to run that in AppConfigCore class, is throwing nullpointer exceptiion. Is there a way we can use rather than defining context.getBean("payloadRequest").

Comment: <bean id ="payloadRequest "
          class = Payload.PayloadRequest">
    </bean>

Comment: have you imported `xml` using `@ ImportResource`update the code in the post @ilovejava